# How to display a specific error to the user, requiring him/her to provide input again using a loop?

Tags: c++

```
using namespace std;

int main(){

    // Variable declarations
    string hours = "";
    double empHours = 0;
    bool cont = true;

    do{
        // Get input of how much employee worked in a week.
        cout << "Enter hours worked in a week: " ;
        getline(cin, hours);

        // Convert the input using string stream for easier validation.
        stringstream hours_input(hours);

        for(int i = 0; i <= hours[i]; i++)
            // Check if input contains any alphabets e.g 90abc, if yes than repeat loop and ask user for input again.
            if(isalpha(hours[i]))
                cont = true;
            // If the input successfully converts to double type
            else if(hours_input >> empHours)
            // Check if values are values >= 0, if yes than exit the loop
                if(empHours >= 0){
                    hours_input >> empHours;    // Assign value to empHours and exit loop
                    cont = false;
            }
            //  Check if input contains special characters or any other form of bad input, if yes than repeat loop and ask user for input again.    
            else    
                cont = true;

    }while(cont);

    cout << "Value is: " << empHours << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is what I have got so far. I am just not sure on how to display the error "That is not a valid option, please try again." and ask for input again. The code works however instead displaying the error mentioned, it displays "Enter hours worked in a week: ".

Simply, keep looping the error "That is not a valid option, please try again." and asking for input, until a valid input is provided.

The valid input should be any integer or float `number >= 0`.
Invalid inputs are any special characters, alphabets and any form of negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a `while` loop.

It could go something like this:

```
while(true){
   cin>>foo;
   if(check if foo is a valid input){
      break; //if the input is valid
  }
cout<<"error, try again";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your code doesn't contain anything to print your error message. You already seem to be handling the error scenario though, so adding it isn't that hard.

If you change the `else` case in your `for` loop like this, it should work:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= hours[i]; i++)
    // Check if input contains any alphabets e.g 90abc, if yes than repeat loop and ask user for input again.
    if(isalpha(hours[i]))
    {
        cout << "That is not a valid option, please try again." << endl;
        cont = true;
    }
    // If the input successfully converts to double type
    else if(hours_input >> empHours)
    // Check if values are values >= 0, if yes than exit the loop
        if(empHours >= 0){
            hours_input >> empHours;    // Assign value to empHours and exit loop
            cont = false;
    }
    //  Check if input contains special characters or any other form of bad input, if yes than repeat loop and ask user for input again.    
    else
    {
        cout << "That is not a valid option, please try again." << endl;
        cont = true;
    }
```

You should however consider refactoring your code a bit to prevent some duplication. If you validate the input in a separate function for example, you can have one clear place of error handling instead of the duplication you have now.